# Highcharts rendering issue in Lightning Component with LockerService enabled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, highcharts

In my Summer '16 organization, I have built a Lightning Component that uses Highcharts to display simple gauge chart. However, it appears that the chart rendering is done in the wrong/unexpected order, such that most labels and some additional elements are hidden.

The expected display (in this case, a demonstration from the Highcharts sample site) is:

[image]

Properly ordered SVG elements:

```
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" width="400" height="300">
    <desc>Created with Highcharts 4.2.6</desc>
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="highcharts-1">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="380" height="239"/>
      </clipPath>
      <linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" id="highcharts-2">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#333" stop-opacity="1"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" id="highcharts-3">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#333" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" id="highcharts-4">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#DDD" stop-opacity="1"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="300" fill="#FFFFFF" class=" highcharts-background"/>
    <path fill="url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer#highcharts-2)" d="M 200 54.783249999999995 A 110.71675 110.71675 0 1 1 199.88928326845274 54.783305358370384 M 200 165.5 A 0 0 0 1 0 200 165.5 "/>
    <path fill="url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer#highcharts-3)" d="M 200 56.814750000000004 A 108.68525 108.68525 0 1 1 199.89131476811414 56.81480434262048 M 200 165.5 A 0 0 0 1 0 200 165.5 " stroke="silver" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path fill="url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer#highcharts-4)" d="M 200 58.84625 A 106.65375 106.65375 0 1 1 199.89334626777557 58.846303326870554 M 200 165.5 A 0 0 0 1 0 200 165.5 " stroke="silver" stroke-width="1"/>
    <path fill="#DDD" d="M 200 58.84625 A 106.65375 106.65375 0 1 1 199.89334626777557 58.846303326870554 M 199.895377767437 60.87780231112063 A 104.62225000000001 104.62225000000001 0 1 0 200 60.87774999999999 "/>
    <path fill="#55BF3B" d="M 149.21249999999995 253.46653038940434 A 101.575 101.575 0 0 1 250.6995080905238 77.48272610232176 L 245.70817084311807 86.14797580920616 A 91.575 91.575 0 0 0 154.21249999999995 244.80627635155997 Z"/>
    <path fill="#DDDF0D" d="M 250.7875 77.53346961059563 A 101.575 101.575 0 0 1 301.57494921250424 165.39842501692908 L 291.5749542125038 165.40842501526242 A 91.575 91.575 0 0 0 245.7875 86.19372364844003 Z"/>
    <path fill="#DF5353" d="M 301.575 165.49999999999991 A 101.575 101.575 0 0 1 250.87544112198046 253.4156989146074 L 245.8667833693858 244.76044920605634 A 91.575 91.575 0 0 0 291.575 165.49999999999991 Z"/>
    <g class="highcharts-grid"/>
    <g class="highcharts-axis">
      <path fill="none" d="M 149.21249999999995 253.46653038940434 L 154.21249999999995 244.80627635155997" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 144.67829001834855 250.6879629390564 L 150.12468036849884 242.30125725960215" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 140.29571299839202 247.67590120363528 L 146.17356552131676 239.5857312598858" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 136.0767812791127 244.4386010349918 L 142.3699851896111 236.66714142042207" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 132.03305865909897 240.98493564786628 L 138.72436472268754 233.55348739309235" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 128.1756287009764 237.32437129902354 L 135.24669651284188 230.2533034871581" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 124.51506435213365 233.46694134090097 L 131.94651260690762 226.7756352773124" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 121.06139896500815 229.42321872088723 L 128.83285857957787 223.13001481038884" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 117.82409879636471 225.20428700160795 L 125.91426874011418 219.3264344786832" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 114.81203706094352 220.82170998165134 L 123.19874274039778 215.37531963150107" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 112.03346961059563 216.28749999999997 L 120.69372364844001 211.28749999999997" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 109.49601230556652 211.61408501104447 L 118.40607754745021 207.074180013649" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 107.20662013995279 206.81427452042436 L 116.3420747163788 202.74690808966636" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 105.17156817854672 201.90122447506386 L 114.50737244351873 198.31754497961086" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 103.39643435731976 196.88840120363528 L 112.9069995202713 193.7982312598858" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 101.88608419468787 191.7895445062885 L 111.54534245757856 189.2013540552633" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 100.64465745546369 186.6186299948139 L 110.42613346280174 184.53951308663628" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 99.67555680404888 181.38983078646143 L 109.55244021000026 179.82548613605914" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 98.98143847796763 176.11747865641186 L 108.92665743165036 175.07219402373534" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 98.56420500730415 170.816024755377 L 108.5505003548499 170.29266519294757" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
      <text x="200" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" class=" highcharts-yaxis-title" style="color:#707070;fill:#707070;" y="114.7125">km/h</text>
      <path fill="none" d="M 149.21249999999995 253.46653038940434 A 101.575 101.575 0 1 1 250.87544112198043 253.4156989146074 M 200 165.5 A 0 0 0 1 0 200 165.5 " stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"/>
    </g>
    <g class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-0 highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible" transform="translate(10,46) scale(1 1)" style="">
      <g style="" transform="translate(178,135)">
        <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="24" height="23" fill="none" stroke="silver" stroke-width="1" rx="3" ry="3"/>
        <text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;text-shadow:0 0 6px #FFFFFF, 0 0 3px #FFFFFF;fill:#000000;text-rendering:geometricPrecision;" y="16">
          <tspan>82</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g class="highcharts-series-group">
      <g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(10,46) scale(1 1)" style="" clip-path="url(http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-speedometer#highcharts-1)">
        <path fill="black" d="M -8.126 -1.5 L 56.882000000000005 -1.5 81.26 -0.5 81.26 0.5 56.882000000000005 1.5 -8.126 1.5 z" transform="translate(190,119.5) rotate(-117 0 0)"/>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="black" transform="translate(190,119.5)"/>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0" transform="translate(10,46) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none"/>
    </g>
    <g class="highcharts-button" style="cursor:default;" stroke-linecap="round" transform="translate(366,10)">
      <title>Chart context menu</title>
      <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="24" height="22" fill="white" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" rx="2" ry="2"/>
      <path fill="#E0E0E0" d="M 6 6.5 L 20 6.5 M 6 11.5 L 20 11.5 M 6 16.5 L 20 16.5" stroke="#666" stroke-width="3"/>
      <text x="0" style="color:black;fill:black;" y="12"/>
    </g>
    <text x="200" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" style="color:#333333;font-size:18px;fill:#333333;width:336px;" y="24">
      <tspan>Speedometer</tspan>
    </text>
    <g class="highcharts-legend">
      <g>
        <g/>
      </g>
    </g>
    <g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels">
      <text x="161.71249999999998" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;width:122px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(-150 161.71249999999998 231.8158952947934)" y="231.8158952947934" opacity="1">
        <tspan>0</tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="0" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;width:122px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(-135 0 -9999)" y="-9999">
        <tspan>10</tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="133.6841047052066" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;width:122px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(-120 133.6841047052066 203.78749999999997)" y="203.78749999999997" opacity="1">
        <tspan>20</tspan>
      </text>
      <text x="0" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;width:122px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(-104.99999999999999 0 -9999)" y="-9999">
        <tspan>30</tspan>
      </text>
    </g>
    <g class="highcharts-tooltip" style="cursor:default;padding:0;pointer-events:none;white-space:nowrap;" transform="translate(0,-9000000000)">
      <path fill="none" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 13.5 0.5 C 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 3.5 L 16.5 13.5 C 16.5 16.5 16.5 16.5 13.5 16.5 L 3.5 16.5 C 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 13.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" stroke-width="5" transform="translate(1, 1)"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 13.5 0.5 C 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 3.5 L 16.5 13.5 C 16.5 16.5 16.5 16.5 13.5 16.5 L 3.5 16.5 C 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 13.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(1, 1)"/>
      <path fill="none" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 13.5 0.5 C 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 3.5 L 16.5 13.5 C 16.5 16.5 16.5 16.5 13.5 16.5 L 3.5 16.5 C 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 13.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.15" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(1, 1)"/>
      <path fill="rgba(249, 249, 249, .85)" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 13.5 0.5 C 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 3.5 L 16.5 13.5 C 16.5 16.5 16.5 16.5 13.5 16.5 L 3.5 16.5 C 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 13.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5"/>
      <text x="8" style="font-size:12px;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" y="20"/>
    </g>
    <text x="390" text-anchor="end" style="cursor:pointer;color:#909090;font-size:9px;fill:#909090;" y="295">Highcharts.com</text>
  </svg>
```

However, in the Lightning component it results in the following:

[image]

Mis-ordered SVG elements:

```
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" style="font-family:&quot;Lucida Grande&quot;, &quot;Lucida Sans Unicode&quot;, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:12px;" width="400" height="300">
      <desc>Created with Highcharts 4.2.6</desc>
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="highcharts-1">
          <rect x="0" y="0" width="380" height="239"/>
        </clipPath>
        <linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" id="highcharts-2">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#333" stop-opacity="1"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" id="highcharts-3">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#333" stop-opacity="1"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1" id="highcharts-4">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="1"/>
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#DDD" stop-opacity="1"/>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <g class="highcharts-tooltip" style="cursor:default;padding:0;pointer-events:none;white-space:nowrap;" transform="translate(0,-9000000000)">
        <path fill="none" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 13.5 0.5 C 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 3.5 L 16.5 13.5 C 16.5 16.5 16.5 16.5 13.5 16.5 L 3.5 16.5 C 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 13.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.049999999999999996" stroke-width="5" transform="translate(1, 1)"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 13.5 0.5 C 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 3.5 L 16.5 13.5 C 16.5 16.5 16.5 16.5 13.5 16.5 L 3.5 16.5 C 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 13.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.09999999999999999" stroke-width="3" transform="translate(1, 1)"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 13.5 0.5 C 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 3.5 L 16.5 13.5 C 16.5 16.5 16.5 16.5 13.5 16.5 L 3.5 16.5 C 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 13.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5" isShadow="true" stroke="black" stroke-opacity="0.15" stroke-width="1" transform="translate(1, 1)"/>
        <path fill="rgba(249, 249, 249, .85)" d="M 3.5 0.5 L 13.5 0.5 C 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 3.5 L 16.5 13.5 C 16.5 16.5 16.5 16.5 13.5 16.5 L 3.5 16.5 C 0.5 16.5 0.5 16.5 0.5 13.5 L 0.5 3.5 C 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 3.5 0.5"/>
        <text x="8" style="font-size:12px;color:#333333;fill:#333333;" y="20"/>
      </g>
      <text x="200" text-anchor="middle" class="highcharts-title" style="color:#333333;font-size:18px;fill:#333333;width:336px;" y="24">
        <tspan>Speedometer</tspan>
      </text>
      <g class="highcharts-legend">
        <g>
          <g/>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-grid"/>
      <g class="highcharts-axis">
        <path fill="none" d="M 149.21249999999995 253.46653038940434 L 154.21249999999995 244.80627635155997" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 144.67829001834855 250.6879629390564 L 150.12468036849884 242.30125725960215" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 140.29571299839202 247.67590120363528 L 146.17356552131676 239.5857312598858" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 136.0767812791127 244.4386010349918 L 142.3699851896111 236.66714142042207" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 132.03305865909897 240.98493564786628 L 138.72436472268754 233.55348739309235" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 128.1756287009764 237.32437129902354 L 135.24669651284188 230.2533034871581" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 124.51506435213365 233.46694134090097 L 131.94651260690762 226.7756352773124" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 121.06139896500815 229.42321872088723 L 128.83285857957787 223.13001481038884" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 117.82409879636471 225.20428700160795 L 125.91426874011418 219.3264344786832" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 114.81203706094352 220.82170998165134 L 123.19874274039778 215.37531963150107" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 112.03346961059563 216.28749999999997 L 120.69372364844001 211.28749999999997" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 109.49601230556652 211.61408501104447 L 118.40607754745021 207.074180013649" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 107.20662013995279 206.81427452042436 L 116.3420747163788 202.74690808966636" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 105.17156817854672 201.90122447506386 L 114.50737244351873 198.31754497961086" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 103.39643435731976 196.88840120363528 L 112.9069995202713 193.7982312598858" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 101.88608419468787 191.7895445062885 L 111.54534245757856 189.2013540552633" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 100.64465745546369 186.6186299948139 L 110.42613346280174 184.53951308663628" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 99.67555680404888 181.38983078646143 L 109.55244021000026 179.82548613605914" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 98.98143847796763 176.11747865641186 L 108.92665743165036 175.07219402373534" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 98.56420500730415 170.816024755377 L 108.5505003548499 170.29266519294757" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 98.425 165.5 L 108.425 165.5" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 98.56420500730415 160.18397524462293 L 108.5505003548499 160.70733480705238" stroke="#666" stroke-width="1" opacity="1"/>
        <path fill="none" d="M 149.21249999999995 253.46653038940434 A 101.575 101.575 0 1 1 250.87544112198043 253.4156989146074 M 200 165.5 A 0 0 0 1 0 200 165.5 " stroke="#C0D0E0" stroke-width="1"/>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-yaxis-labels">
        <text x="161.71249999999998" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;width:122px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(-150 161.71249999999998 231.8158952947934)" y="231.8158952947934" opacity="1">
          <tspan>0</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="0" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;width:122px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(-135 0 -9999)" y="-9999">
          <tspan>10</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="133.6841047052066" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;width:122px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(-120 133.6841047052066 203.78749999999997)" y="203.78749999999997" opacity="1">
          <tspan>20</tspan>
        </text>
        <text x="0" style="color:#606060;cursor:default;font-size:11px;fill:#606060;width:122px;text-overflow:clip;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0) rotate(-104.99999999999999 0 -9999)" y="-9999">
          <tspan>30</tspan>
        </text>
      </g>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="300" fill="#FFFFFF" class=" highcharts-background"/>
      <path fill="url(#highcharts-2)" d="M 200 54.783249999999995 A 110.71675 110.71675 0 1 1 199.88928326845274 54.783305358370384 M 200 165.5 A 0 0 0 1 0 200 165.5 "/>
      <path fill="url(#highcharts-3)" d="M 200 56.814750000000004 A 108.68525 108.68525 0 1 1 199.89131476811414 56.81480434262048 M 200 165.5 A 0 0 0 1 0 200 165.5 " stroke="silver" stroke-width="1"/>
      <path fill="url(#highcharts-4)" d="M 200 58.84625 A 106.65375 106.65375 0 1 1 199.89334626777557 58.846303326870554 M 200 165.5 A 0 0 0 1 0 200 165.5 " stroke="silver" stroke-width="1"/>
      <path fill="#DDD" d="M 200 58.84625 A 106.65375 106.65375 0 1 1 199.89334626777557 58.846303326870554 M 199.895377767437 60.87780231112063 A 104.62225000000001 104.62225000000001 0 1 0 200 60.87774999999999 "/>
      <path fill="#55BF3B" d="M 149.21249999999995 253.46653038940434 A 101.575 101.575 0 0 1 250.6995080905238 77.48272610232176 L 245.70817084311807 86.14797580920616 A 91.575 91.575 0 0 0 154.21249999999995 244.80627635155997 Z"/>
      <path fill="#DDDF0D" d="M 250.7875 77.53346961059563 A 101.575 101.575 0 0 1 301.57494921250424 165.39842501692908 L 291.5749542125038 165.40842501526242 A 91.575 91.575 0 0 0 245.7875 86.19372364844003 Z"/>
      <path fill="#DF5353" d="M 301.575 165.49999999999991 A 101.575 101.575 0 0 1 250.87544112198046 253.4156989146074 L 245.8667833693858 244.76044920605634 A 91.575 91.575 0 0 0 291.575 165.49999999999991 Z"/>
      <g class="highcharts-series-group">
        <g class="highcharts-series highcharts-series-0 highcharts-tracker" transform="translate(10,46) scale(1 1)" style="" clip-path="url(#highcharts-1)">
          <path fill="black" d="M -8.126 -1.5 L 56.882000000000005 -1.5 81.26 -0.5 81.26 0.5 56.882000000000005 1.5 -8.126 1.5 z" transform="translate(190,119.5) rotate(-120.00000000000001 0 0)"/>
          <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="black" transform="translate(190,119.5)"/>
        </g>
        <g class="highcharts-markers highcharts-series-0" transform="translate(10,46) scale(1 1)" clip-path="none"/>
      </g>
      <g class="highcharts-data-labels highcharts-series-0 highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible" transform="translate(10,46) scale(1 1)" style="">
        <g style="" transform="translate(178,135)">
          <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="24" height="23" fill="none" stroke="silver" stroke-width="1" rx="3" ry="3"/>
          <text x="5" style="font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#000000;text-shadow:0 0 6px #FFFFFF, 0 0 3px #FFFFFF;fill:#000000;text-rendering:geometricPrecision;" y="16">
            <tspan>80</tspan>
          </text>
        </g>
      </g>
      <text x="390" text-anchor="end" style="cursor:pointer;color:#909090;font-size:9px;fill:#909090;" y="295">Highcharts.com</text>
    </svg>
```

As you can see, the Lightning framework with LockerService enabled appears to cause the SVG elements to be mis-ordered. No errors or warnings are shown in the log, only the result is wrong.

Does anyone know of a way to resolve this, short of disabling the LockerService?

An unmanaged package with source code to reproduce is included in the comments below.

Comment: An unmanaged package with sample code to reproduce the error is here: https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t28000000YHjH

Comment: Have confirmed now that this issue does not happen in organizations where LockerService is deactivated. Something specifically in the LockerService is interacting badly with Highcharts. Is anyone else facing this issue?

Comment: Hi @JCherry Did you try using Highcharts version 5 which implements strict mode with Locker Service active? I see in the above code that you're using 4.2.6. Could you please give a try with Highcharts version 5?

Comment: This does appear to be resolved now with Highcharts version 5, thank you.